# Does category theory only deal with immutable objects? If so, why?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory

IIUC, category theory only applies to immutable objects, and mutability is modelled within that using e.g. functors, monads. Is that true? If so, why doesn't category theory include immutability? Has no-one got round to adding that, or is it impossible?

I'm asking because I've never seen category theory applied to, or discussed in the context of, imperative code or languages, and I want to know if it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. The [state monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) expresses mutable state that can be used in a computation, and that is just one example.

A second example is [Frank Oles's PhD thesis](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/fox-19/member/jcr/www/FrankOlesThesis.pdf), supervised by John Reynolds, where a presheaf model of Algol, a procedural language with mutable variable, is given. This work was subsequently extended and adapted.

Comment: I'm used to the state monad being `s => (s, a)`, which isn't mutable in the sense that a particular section of memory is modified. Have I misunderstood sth?

Comment: `s` is (the type of) memory.

Comment: do you mean the implementation in functional languages, where a new value is created rather than the original mutated, is just one implementation of `s => (s, a)`, and an imperative one would also be valid? See also my question edit

Comment: No, I mean categorical models of procedural languages. The state monad is just the simplest example to understand. I provided another reference to dispell any doubts.

Comment: OK, thanks. In that case my next question (which I'm not asking you to answer) is why do we say functional programming enables composition if category theory also applies to procedural languages?

Comment: I would suggest learning more. Frank Oles's thesis is pretty well written, for example. But to answer your question: there are many facets to composability. Imperative languages are composable too, just in a different category, namely the Kleisli category of the monad that models whatever effects are present in the language. There is a *lot* of theory, do not presume you can imagine how things work without learning at least some of it first.